# how to populate a field according to the other form fields' values in antd ProForm?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have created a form using Ant Design ProForm that includes 4 fields. When the user inputs values in the 'Interval', 'Unit', and 'Last Due Date' fields, I want to calculate the value for the 'Next Due Date' field and display it in the corresponding field. 'Next Due Date' is calculated in "calculateDueDate" function but I am unable to display it. I tried using 'setFieldValue' but it doesn't work in 'antd ProForm'. How can I display the calculated value in the 'Next Due Date' field?
Here is my code Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-proform-xkt6wm

And here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [intervalDays, setIntervalDays] = useState();
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState();
  const [lastDueDate, setLastDueDate] = useState();
  const [nextDueDate, setNextDueDate] = useState();

  const calculateDueDate = () => {
    const interval = intervalDays;
    const dueDate = new Date(lastDueDate);

    if (unit === "1") {
      dueDate.setDate(dueDate.getDate() + interval);
    } else if (unit === "2") {
      dueDate.setMonth(dueDate.getMonth() + interval);
    }
    const year = dueDate.getFullYear();
    const month = String(dueDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    const day = String(dueDate.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    const nextDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    console.log(nextDate);
    setNextDueDate(nextDate);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (intervalDays && lastDueDate && unit) {
      calculateDueDate();
    }
  }, [intervalDays, unit, lastDueDate]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
        <ProForm layout="horizontal">
          <ProForm.Group>
            <ProFormDigit
              onChange={(value) => setIntervalDays(value)}
              name="interval"
              label="Interval"
              width="sm"
            />
            <ProFormSelect
              onChange={(value) => setUnit(value)}
              name="kindOfDate"
              label="Unit"
              width="md"
              options={[
                {
                  value: "1",
                  label: "Day(s)"
                },
                {
                  value: "2",
                  label: "Month(s)"
                }
              ]}
            />
          </ProForm.Group>
          <ProForm.Group>
            <ProFormDatePicker
              onChange={(value) => setLastDueDate(value)}
              name="lastDueDate"
              label="Last Due Date"
            />
            <ProFormDatePicker
              onChange={(value) => setNextDueDate(value)}
              name="nextDueDate"
              label="Next Due Date"
            />
          </ProForm.Group>
        </ProForm>
      </ConfigProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Pass `value={nextDueDate}` to NextDueDatePicker